# How to access WKWebView from didReceiveScriptMessage in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, webkit, wkwebview

I am trying to achieve communication between web and native application by using `WKWebView` and Javascript interfaces.

I have a `UITableView` and each `UITableViewCell` contains a `WKWebView`.
I add each WKWebView a `WKUserContentController` and in those content controllers, I add a `scriptMessageHandler`.

However, in my didReceiveScriptMessage method, I don't know which `WKWebView` received the message from web.

How do I access the `WKWebView` from `didReceiveScriptMessage` method?

What is best way to determine which WKWebView received the message?

My Code:

```
func userContentController(userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceiveScriptMessage message: WKScriptMessage) {

        if message.name == "callbackHandler"{

            self.title = message.body as? String ?? "none"

        }
}
```

`WKWebView` initialization

```
let config = WKWebViewConfiguration()
config.preferences.javaScriptEnabled = true
let contentController = WKUserContentController()
contentController.addScriptMessageHandler(self, name: "callbackHandler")
let webview = WKWebView(frame: CGRectZero, configuration: config)
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears WKScriptMessage have a property called webview.